# Update SQL rows that have same identifier with different values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that is structured like so:

| parentId | Name | uuid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | 312312 |
| 1 | null | 345345 |
| 2 | null | 654645 |
| 3 | null | 567567 |
| 3 | null | 521232 |
| 3 | null | 472891 |
| 3 | null | 948202 |

I need to use an update query to update the name column of each. All I have to identify which rows need updating is the parentId, NOT the uuid.

Expected outcome:

| parentId | Name | uuid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | someName | 312312 |
| 1 | anotherName | 345345 |
| 2 | yetAnotherName | 654645 |
| 3 | youGetTheIdea | 567567 |
| 3 | blah | 521232 |
| 3 | blah1 | 472891 |
| 3 | blah2ElectricBoogaloo | 948202 |

Is this possible? It doesn't matter which order they're inserted.

The data I have to insert is similar to:

```
[{parentId: 1, name: someName}, {parentId: 1, name: anotherName}, etc... ]
```

Comment: What DBMS you are using? (My Sql, Sql Server, Oracle, etc..). Please update tags

Comment: Mysql, updated!

Comment: What is **precise** MySQL version?

Comment: provide sample source data as textual formatted CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts. Provide complete data for insertion value. Provide desired final data state after the insertion completed.